# Refactoring fopen_s

Tags: c++

I am attempting to refactor a very old piece of code that generates a log file:

```
FILE *File = NULL;

    errno_t err = fopen_s(&File, m_pApp->LogFilename(), "a+");      //  Open log file to append to

    if (err == 0)
    {
        ::fprintf(File, "Date,Time,Serial Number,ASIC Voltage,Ink Temp,Heater Temp, Heater Set Point, PSOC Version,");
        if (m_ExtraLog)
            ::fprintf(File, "T1 Temperature,ASIC Temperature,Proc Temperature,Voltage mA");
        ::fprintf(File, "\n");
        fclose(File);
    }
```

The reason for refactoring is that some users report that it is not possible to copy the file that is being produced (they want to copy it so that it can be analysed by a labview program). I read the documentation regarding fopen_s and saw that "Files that are opened by fopen_s and _wfopen_s are not sharable" - is this the cause of my problem? I am unsure because actually, I do not see the copying problem and seem to be able to copy and paste the file without issue. In any case I have replaced it with the recommended _fsopen function like so:

```
FILE *File = NULL;

if((File = _fsopen(m_pApp->LogFilename(),"a+", _SH_DENYNO))!= NULL)
    {
        ::fprintf(File, "Date,Time,Serial Number,ASIC Voltage,Ink Temp,Heater Temp, Heater Set Point, PSOC Version,");

        if(m_ExtraLog)
        {
            ::fprintf(File, "T1 Temperature,ASIC Temperature,Proc Temperature,Voltage mA");
        }

        ::fprintf(File, "\n");
        fclose(File);
    }
```

I've given the refactored code to the user but they still report being unable to copy or access the file from labview. I have very limited knowledge of C++ so I am wondering is there any other explanation as to why the file being generated is not able to copied by another process?

Comment: I assume from the quote from documentation that you are using Windows, is this correct ?

Comment: How often is this function being called?  Neither version should have any handle contention after `fclose()` is called.  Either the other program just happens to try to open the log while you're writing to it (very possible if this function is called many times per second), or something else is going on.

Comment: It's indeed Windows, or more accurately MSVC++. It's not a standard function.

Answer (score 0):

Lets have look into [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/z5hh6ee9(v=vs.90).aspx)

> Open a file. These are versions of fopen, _wfopen with security enhancements as described in Security Enhancements in the CRT.

Follow by: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/8ef0s5kh(v=vs.90).aspx)

We can read:

> Filesystem security. Secure file I/O APIs support secure file access in the default case.

So to fix that, you must change 'file security' to match 'all users/read access'